Google meet can't share screen or window on Mac 12
For some reason I'm unable to share a window or full screen on Chrome with Google Meet on Mac. Versions:
Chrome:(Official Build) (x86_64)
Mac: 12
In the Mac settings under security, screen recording is enabled for Chrome. I've tried restarting Chrome, restarting the computer, disabling and enabling screen recording for Chrome from the settings (with Chrome restarts in between) but nothing seems to work. The screen sharing also doesn't work for google meet (the app).


PS: Also, screenshots can be made with Cmd-Shift-3 and Cmd-Shift-4.
